# Elasticsearch - mutiplication of 2 fields and then sum aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, multiplication

I'm trying to make a simple query in elasticsearch but I can't figure out how to do it. I searched all over the internet and there was no discussion on this situation.

Let's say I have items like those:

```
{
  "item_id": 1,
  "item_price": 100,
  "item_quantity": 2
},
{
  "item_id": 2,
  "item_price": 200,
  "item_quantity": 3
},
{
  "item_id": 3,
  "item_price": 150,
  "item_quantity": 1
},
{
  "item_id": 4,
  "item_price": 250,
  "item_quantity": 5
}
```

I want to make a query that will give me the result of  the total price in the stock.

for example: 100*2 + 200*3 + 150*1 + 250*5

the result for this query supposed to be 2,200

---

The answer query for the last data is working, But what about this complex situation:

```
POST tests/test2/
{
  "item_category": "aaa",
  "items": 
  [
    {
      "item_id": 1,
      "item_price": 100,
      "item_quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "item_id": 2,
      "item_price": 150,
      "item_quantity": 4
    }
  ]
}

POST tests/test2/
{
  "item_category": "bbb",
  "items": 
  [
    {
      "item_id": 3,
      "item_price": 200,
      "item_quantity": 3
    },
    {
      "item_id": 4,
      "item_price": 200,
      "item_quantity": 5
    }
  ]
}

POST tests/test2/
{
  "item_category": "ccc",
  "items": 
  [
    {
      "item_id": 5,
      "item_price": 300,
      "item_quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "item_id": 6,
      "item_price": 150,
      "item_quantity": 8
    }
  ]
}

POST tests/test2/
{
  "item_category": "ddd",
  "items": 
  [
    {
      "item_id": 7,
      "item_price": 80,
      "item_quantity": 10
    },
    {
      "item_id": 8,
      "item_price": 250,
      "item_quantity": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case the next query is not working and give me a wrong answer (1,420 instead of 6,000):

```
GET tests/test2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": { }
  },
    "aggs": {
        "total_price": {
            "sum": {
                "script": {
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "inline": "doc['items.item_price'].value * doc['items.item_quantity'].value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `sum` aggregation for values calculated using `script`

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "total_price": {
            "sum": {
                "script": {
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "inline": "doc['item_price'].value * doc['item_quantity'].value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html#_script_9 for more details

**Update**

As for your advanced case, it would be better to map your `items` field as `nested` type, after that you can use this aggregation

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "nested": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "items"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "total_price": {
                    "sum": {
                        "script": {
                            "inline": "doc['items.item_price'].value * doc['items.item_quantity'].value"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the mapping query for the example DB in the question:

```
PUT tests
{
  "mappings": {
    "test2": {
      "properties": {
        "items": {
          "type": "nested" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

just to clarify, You must make the mapping query before the index has been created. (changing mapping for existing field is not allowed).

Comment: Great, It's working for this case, but my situation is a little bit more complex and I tried the same algorithm but it fails to bring to right answer. I'm updating my question to the real situation that I need to Sum, Please take a look to see what I did wrong.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but it gives an ERROR:."[nested] nested path [items] is not nested", I tried to fix it with no success. do you have any idea what it can be?

Comment: As I said, you should change your mapping to make this field nested. Take a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer, very helpful and gave me the answer I need. Please accept the edit for your answer, so beginners like me will understand the mapping thing.